# ipdb debug not executing on breakpoint

Tags: python, django, pdb, ipdb

I can not understand why is `ipdb` entering `manage.py` every time I start server, my breakpoint is set inside `restapi/views.py` and I'm starting my server with `python -m ipdb manage.py runserver 192.168.33.11:8080`, I'm working on `vagrant`.

This is my `ipdb` log when I start my server

```
> /home/vagrant/vincluos/VincluCMSProject/manage.py(2)<module>()
      1 #!/usr/bin/env python
----> 2 import os
      3 import sys

ipdb>
```

How come that `ipdb` does not recognize my breakpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I have manage to sort this thing by running standard `python manage.py runserver ipaddress` instead of `python -m ipdb manage.py runserver ipaddress`